# Cpanel recursive php.ini

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

So I decided to move my VPS server to another provider because I wanted to move my websites closer to home (Southeast Asia). With little knowledge on web hosting, I didn’t hesitate to move it becuase who would have thought it will be this hard to recompile PHP, right?

Scenario: I have a website running under Wordpress so I have a PHP.ini file in the root folder. Under one domain, I have 10 subdomains. Each subdomain works as a POS system of each sites we have, all my subdomain files are placed in /home/[user]/[folder]/[subdomain].

Question #1: is it safe to say that the subdomains are in a secure file location? Reason why the subdomains aren’t placed in “public_html” is becuase I don’t want bots/users to be accessing domain.com/[subdomain folder name].

Question #2: Under the folder subdomains, I have to edit a PHP.ini configuration “max_input_vars” for all subdomain but I want to achive it thru one PHP.INI file only. Is it possible?

Comment: this belongs on [sf]

Comment: Q1, if the files are outside of the web root they are not going to be accessible by any one (outside the domain), this does not sound like what you want.

Comment: @smith subdomains are pointed outside the public_html folder